# Theme_HoloEverywhereLight_Sherlock showing dark background

Tags: android, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using Christophe Versiuex's [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) library in concert with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to display an ICS looking app on Gingerbread phones.  The Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock theme works great.  But when I try to change the theme to Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock, all the text changes to dark text, but the Activity backgrounds stay dark.

All I'm doing is:

```
  setTheme(R.style.Theme_HoloEverywhereLight_Sherlock);
  setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

in the Activity.onCreate() method.

In looking at the code, it defines:

```
<style name="Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_holo_light</item>
    .
    .
    .
```

so it looks like it should work.

Has anyone else used the Light theme and gotten a light background?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.  I was doing:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTheme(R.style.Theme_HoloEverywhereLight_Sherlock);
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

when I should have been doing:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_HoloEverywhereLight_Sherlock);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

setTheme() needed to be called before super.onCreate().  Now the light theme works like a charm.