# ActionBasSherlock, Holoeverywhere and themes

Tags: android, themes, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to implement the choice of two themes, Dark and Light.

The dark one is working fine, but when I choose the light theme it's rendered not correctly (the action bar is light, the text is dark but the backgorund is still dark).

By the way in the eclipse preview it's shown correctly.

I'm using the dev branch from Holoeverywhere and I'm extending the themes like this:

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Holo.Theme"/>
    <style name="LightTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Any help?

**EDIT**

I've just tried with the emulator (3.2, on a tablet) and it's showing the theme correctly.
I will do a couple of tests and eventually open an issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution: [Theme_HoloEverywhereLight_Sherlock showing dark background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172965/theme-holoeverywherelight-sherlock-showing-dark-background)

(I've looked for hours and it came up just now.)

Basically the setTheme should be done before everything, even before the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`, I was doing it just after..